# How do I replace an end of file <script> with JS in Rails with asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have an HTML file that I am transposing to an ERB view in my Rails app.

However, in the HTML, I have a snippet of JS that has to be run last (after everything else) because it handles the way the page scrolls.

So we have all of the HTML, then right before the `</body>`, I have this:

```
<script>
   // Some awesome JS that controls the scrollbar
</script>
```

But I haven't figured out how to make it work within Asset Pipeline, following Rails conventions, properly.

This file is my `Home#Index`, which is the marketing website for my app for non-logged in users.

If I put this `<script>` tag at the top of the layout that governs this `Home#Index`, it doesn't work.

If I move this JS to be inside my `app/assets/javascripts/home.js` that also doesn't work, because it loads `home.js` before it loads `application.js`.

I also don't want to put this inside `application.js` because it will interfere with other classes throughout the rest of my app that are similarly named.

What's the best RAILSy way to do this without just doing `<script>JS</script>` inside my `app/views/home/index.html.erb`, because that just feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps may solve your problem:

```
step:1 app/views/home/index.html.erb (provide source of JS.)

<%= javascript_include_tag 'custom/xyz.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

step 2: assets/javascrips/custom/xyz.js (JS goes here)

$(function(){
  //js code goes here
});

step 3: application.js  (the require_directory directive which includes all JavaScript files only in the directory specified, without recursion.)

//= require_directory .

step 4: application.rb

config.assets.precompile += %w(custom/*.js)
```